# How to add a field to an array of objects using useState in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm building an app in react native and I want a way in which I can regularly add a field to one ore all of the user data before pushing it to the database, It is an array of objects and I know the index of each object. I'm aware of object destructuring but I don't know how to go about this.
In the example below, how do I add the field "hobby" and a value of "Football" to smith alone? Thanks in advance.

```
const [usersData, setUsersData] = useState([
  {
    name: "Jane",
    sex: "female",
    age: "20",
  },
  {
    name: "Doe",
    sex: "male",
    age: "29",
  },
  {
    name: "Smith",
    sex: "male",
    age: "24",
  },
]);

const addHobby = (index, hobby) => {
  //Adding the field here//
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to achieve this:

```
const addHobby = (index, hobby) => {
  let temp = [...usersData] // Create a copy with the spread operator
  temp[index].hobby = hobby // Set new field
  setUsersData(temp) // Save the copy to state
}

...

addHobby(2, "Football") // 2 being known index of "Smith"
```

---

**Edit:**  As suggested by @EmileBergeron, the spread operator creates a shallow copy only, which means the original state will still be mutated in case of object property changes. A more react friendly approach would be to use `.map()`

```
const addHobby = (index, hobby) => {

  // Create a copy using .map()
  const temp = usersData.map((data, idx) => {
    let tempData = {...data} // Copy object
    if(idx === index) tempData.hobby = hobby // Set new field
    return tempData
  }) 
  
  setUsersData(temp) // Save the copy to state
}
```

Comment: `temp[index].hobby = hobby` mutates the current state.

Comment: How's that, if `temp` is created using the `...` operator?

Comment: It creates a shallow copy of the array, but you're still accessing the same objects that are in the state currently.

Comment: Thanks @EmileBergeron, Let me give it a try.

Comment: Thanks @EmileBergeron, It worked for me. I really appreciate

Comment: The edited version updates the array without mutating the current state, which is good, though it does unnecessarily copy every objects of the array when only one needs to be cloned.